# Signed variables - T/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Plus varchar(1) = '+'
        ,@Minus varchar(1) = '-'
```

-- My Try

```
SELECT 5 + (@Plus*2) AS [Should_be_7], 5 + (@Minus*2) AS [Should_be_3], 5 - (@Plus*2) AS [Should_be_3], 5 - (@Minus*2) AS [Should_be_7]
```

/*
My Output

```
Should_be_7 Should_be_3 Should_be_3 Should_be_7
5           5           5           5
```

My goal: To use signs from variable and do calculations. (I know I am trying to use characters with int in my math while expecting output in int and that a NO-NO at the most fundamental level of math...the query is just to show you what I am trying to do).
I am open for alternative datatypes for INT as long as I can do CAST/CONVERT +/- to that datatype.

Expected output:

```
Should_be_7 Should_be_3 Should_be_3 Should_be_7
7           3           3           3
```

*/

UPDATE (kind of different Q...so sorry):

There can be a SINGLE variable which can be + or _ at any time and I need to use just that variable to get Expected output...is that possible?

```
DECLARE @Sign varchar(1) = '+' -- or can be '-"
```

-- My Try

-- WHEN SIGN IS '+'
    SELECT 5 + (@Sign*2) AS [Should_be_7],  5 - (@Sign*2) AS [Should_be_7]
-- WHEN SIGN IS '-'
    SELECT 5 + (@Sign*2) AS [Should_be_3], 5 - (@Sign*2) AS [Should_be_3]

/*
Expected output: 
-- WHEN SIGN IS '+'

```
Should_be_7 Should_be_7
7           3
```

-- WHEN SIGN IS '-'

```
Should_be_3 Should_be_3
3           7
```

*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server converts strings to numbers in an arithmetic context.  So,

```
select '-1' - 2, '+1' + 2;
```

Produces the expected value of -3 and 3 respectively.

What you are observing as variables is that `'-'` and `'+'` are turned into 0s.  That is very reasonable behavior.  All 4 of your expressions should return 5 and they do, on SQL Fiddle in SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Comment: I see it. I need to convert +/- varchar to +1/-1 varchar and use it without any conversion in my calculations..

Comment: @user1569220 . . . That would be one solution.  Remember to have the `varchar()` be at least `varchar(2)` -- otherwise, only one character will be stored in the variable (and it will be the sign).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make the variables ints and assign 1 and -1 to them?

Comment: These signs are coming from a column with 1000+ records (one record could be +, other could be -, and then other could be +, and so on

Comment: So what is the end result that you want to see from doing this logic? It helps to say what you are actually trying to accomplish instead of asking how to fix what you currently have, then trickling in the 'oh yea's .

Comment: I have a column (C_Sign) which can have + or - (varchar(1)). I want to use that column and do X + ((C_Sign)*Int) and X - ((C_Sign)*Int)...I think It's better if I create a new thread.

Comment: How about creating a computed column that is a combination of the sign column and the Int column?  You can then use that column wherever else you need it.

Comment: Looks like I will have to create one derived column and do concatenation. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28907)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Plus int = 1
 ,@Minus int = -1
SELECT 5 + (@Plus*2) AS [Should_be_7], 
5 + (@Minus*2) AS [Should_be_3], 
5 - (@Plus*2) AS [Should_be_3_2], 
5 - (@Minus*2) AS [Should_be_7_2]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28907/0)**:

```
| SHOULD_BE_7 | SHOULD_BE_3 | SHOULD_BE_3_2 | SHOULD_BE_7_2 |
|-------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|           7 |           3 |             3 |             7 |
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
cast((@Plus + '1') as int)
cast((@Minus + '1') as int)
```

Should be easy enough to programatically work into your code.

Comment: What if I only have one variable which can be either + or minus and I have to aggregate based on that one variable? Any way to avoid CASE?

Comment: Im not fully grasping the issue here... are you saying there will be one variable with either a '-' or '+' value?

Comment: If you are open to different datatypes, use RedFilter's code. If you must use a varchar, there is no need for a case statement. Just use 
cast((@Sign + '1') as int). Multiplying a number by +1 will just keep it the same while multiplying it by -1 will flip the sign.